# Excel match multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I need some help with an excel formula. I have 2 tables as on the screenshot below:

[image: excel image]

The first table "AD Groups & apps" contains all the required AD groups for one application to work. Now I need to match all applications from the second table "Users AD Groups" to the first table and have a result table as the third one "Users Apps".

I need to automate as some applications are dependend on one group, other apps on 2 or 3 AD groups (group names are exactly like the ones on the screenshot - not really userfriendly)

Few assumptions:

- On the 2nd table there could be groups not related to the required apps
- The result table needs to show only application names where all pre-reqs are available

Tried messing with vlookups and index/match but got lost somewhere.

If its not asking too much, any tips on changing the same to show apps where user is member of the first column group, but is missing groups from 2nd/3rd column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easy to accomplish with a single formula....but you can use this version in H4 confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$4:C$11,F$4:F$11,0))+(A$4:C$11=""),ROW(F$4:F$11)),ROW(F$4:F$11))=3,ROW(F$4:F$11)),ROWS(H$4:H4))),"")`

That should give you all the D4:D11 values where all specified group values are shown

for a single group that would be easier, e.g. for those where Group 1 only needs to be checked try this version

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$4:A$11,F$4:F$11,0)),ROW(F$4:F$11)),ROWS(H$4:H4))),"")`